# How can I find a list of all the php files that are called when a page loads?

Tags: php, linux, joomla

I'm taking over a website for my job. The last developer didn't understand the architecture of our CMS and hacked his way around everything. Also, he documented nothing.

I need to track back and see what files are being called when a website is called? What's the easiest way to do this?

I know I can do:

```
ps aux | grep php
```

That only shows me the *currently* running scripts though. If I don't run the command at the right time I'll miss stuff.

How can I view a log of every file that's run when a URL is called? This is a basic LAMP stack.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'scripts'? Php files that are being loaded? Something else?

Comment: PHP files being loaded. Sorry. Should have been more clear.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question so the accepted answer makes more sense

Comment: @stevebaros If you are going to edit a post, changing one letter isn't a great edit.  Be sure to also remove any sign-offs, thanks in advances, signatures, and taglines.  If you can only edit to change one letter, its probably better to focus on another page that has a greater need for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from within PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

use `get_included_files()` to get an array of all that have been included using `include`, `include_once`, `require` or `require_once`.

You could then do this:

```
register_shutdown_function( function(){
  echo implode( PHP_EOL, get_included_files() );
} );
```

At which point you could write the list to disk with each execution.